# Administrator section for a website - ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-3.5

I have a website for which I need to implement the admin interface. The functionality is pretty generic and should include CRUD operations to DB tables and charts etc.

I know I can whip up something pretty quickly using the GridView control but was wondering if there's something open source that supports this functionality so that I don't have to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked into [ASP.NET Dynamic Data](http://www.asp.net/DynamicData/) (my bold):

> ASP.NET Dynamic Data brings major
>   usability and RAD development changes
>   to the existing ASP.NET data controls.
>   RAD development is significantly
>   increased by the use of a rich
>   scaffolding framework. After you add a
>   LINQ to SQL or Entity Framework data
>   model to a project, you can simply
>   register it with Dynamic Data. **The
>   result is a fully functional Web site.**
>   Full CRUD (create, read, update, and
>   delete) operations are supported.

This would at least get the "CRUD" data-manipulation part of the site out of the way for you with minimal effort. There's also an [ASP.NET Charting control](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/mschart/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=1591) that you could take a look at, which Scott Guthrie gave an [overview of](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/11/24/new-asp-net-charting-control-lt-asp-chart-runat-quot-server-quot-gt.aspx), I have to say I haven't yet used it but it does look pretty good.

Comment: @Rob - It supports only Linq 2 Sql or EF?

Comment: @DotnetDude, you're working in .net 3.5, so is that a problem?

Comment: Not really. However, it's not consistent with the home grown data access that the rest of the app uses.